# How to completely remove a merged commit from Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I recently had to do a `git revert <commit-id>` of a merged commit that should have never been merged, however, when I look at the branch, the merge is still there, what step did I miss?

So I believe I was successful in reverting <commit_id> Merged from `this_branch` to `that_branch`, but when I look at `this_branch` it still has the merged work, but that commit is now faded out in Bitbucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to reset the branch and replace the remote version. This is destructive and disruptive to other developers as they'll need to check out the replacement branch even if it has the same name. Something like this:

```
// reset local branch to earlier commit
git reset <commit hash prior to faulty commit> --hard

// force push; could also delete the remote first
git push origin -f
```

If you need commits *after* the faulty one, create a backup branch before doing the reset and cherry-pick those commits to the replacement branch after the reset.